# Calculate parbox width to make it meet the page border?

Tags: boxes, calculations, width

I'm using the `program` package to typeset my algorithms. I want my comments to have a light gray background, therefore I'm using `colorbox` with a `parbox` inside (for multi-line comments).

Now the problem is that when I want to insert a comment in an **indented** line, setting the `parbox`'s width to `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` will make it too big, crossing the right page border.

I'm looking for a way to compute the `parbox`'s width based on the current indentation (which I can't seem to find out) or its horizontal starting position so that it always goes up to the right page border.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here's a minimum working example. The `renewcommand` commented out is the solution suggested first, but it doesn't work here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{commentcolor}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\commentbox}[1] {\colorbox{commentcolor}{\parbox{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}
%\renewcommand{\commentbox}[1] {\noindent\colorbox{commentcolor}{\parbox{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{programbox}
\commentbox{A normal comment.}
\IF someCondition
    \THEN
        \commentbox{An indented comment.}
        myVar := myVar + 1
\FI
\end{programbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your document always uses LaTeX constructs then

```
 \usepackage{calc}
```

...

```
\noindent\colorbox{red}\parbox{\linewidth - 2\fboxsep}{....}}
```

should work. (If not please provide a full MWE that shows the problem)

---

In a tabbing environment everything is different, but LaTeX has already measured everything to set the tab stops so you just need to dig out the lengths. The following definition includes a `-15pt` which is accounting for some extra space from `program` so it is probably possible to replace that with a suitable internal from that package if you know it well. (I haven't used it before:-)  But If you get it wrong TeX tells you how much the box is over-full in the log so just subtracted that amount.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{commentcolor}{gray}{0.9}
\makeatletter


\newcommand{\commentbox}[1] {%
  \noindent\colorbox{commentcolor}{%
        \parbox{\linewidth- \dimen\@curtab - 2\fboxsep - 15pt}{%
           \raggedright#1}}}

\begin{document}




\noindent X \dotfill X


\begin{programbox}

\commentbox{A normal comment.}
\IF someCondition
    \THEN
        \commentbox{An indented comment.
                    with 2 lines}
        myVar := myVar + 1
\FI
\end{programbox}


\noindent X \dotfill X

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't do the job. I will edit my question now and add an MWE.

Comment: Ah you are in  a hidden `tabbing` environment.

Comment: Yes ... "indented" was a bit misleading I guess.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I didn't know about `curtab`. I was looking for this, but couldn't find it anywhere. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: It probably isn't documented anywhere other than the latex sources, it's not intended to be a user-command:-)